# Use content of a file in the path to a second file

Tags: python

I want to insert into a path the content of a txt file.

Example:

I have a txt file  in `./path/date.txt` with the content

```
08122016
```

How do I put the content (`08122016`) on the path of a second file?

Something like this:

```
s = open('/erp/date/**date.txt content**').read()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#open the date file
f = open("./path/date.txt", 'r')
#read the content
content=f.read()
#close file
f.close()

#insert date in path
s=open("/erp/date/"+str(content)).read()
```

Comment: No, that's not how paths are build. https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join exists.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```
import os

with open(r'./path/date.txt', 'rt') as input_file:
    data = input_file.read()
with open(os.path.join('/erp/date', data), 'rt') as input_file2:
    data2 = input_file2.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert strings into other strings like that (python 2.7.12):

`path = 'home/user/path/%s' % content`

The %s in the the string will be replaced by the content variable.

Comment: Python comes with batteries included: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join